# unique indexes in mongodb if we use sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In sharding enviroments data are stored in different shards bases on ranges of shard key. It seems to me that in this case mongodb can't guarantee uniqueness of indexes (at least if it's not shard key). Can we use unique index for shard key? Can we use index on fields other than shard key?

Comment: As of MongoDB 4.x the rules are as follows regarding shard key and unique indexes. See this documentation for more details: [Shard Key and Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#unique-indexes). Also, unique index can be used as shard key only for Ranged sharding not for Hashed sharding. Hashed sharding uses hashed index on the shard key, and hashed indexes do not support unique constraint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct, mongodb cannot guarantee uniqueness on indexes across a sharded cluster, as each shard cannot report on whether it contains the key to be inserted is unique in their context.

This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#limit-sharding-unique-indexes) and there are a [number](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-mongodb-ensure-unique-id-field-values-when-using-a-shard-key-other-than-id) of [strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/) around this circumstance.

The outcome is that you will need your application layer to enforce uniqueness of the shard key, if such a key is picked for a shard key.

I'm not 100% clear on what your second question is referring to.  You can have indexes on collections other than the shard key, and these can be used to improve performance for queries, but any queries that do not use the shard key will be scatter/gather (and therefore hit every shard).  The performance when they hit each shard will be dependant on how good the index is, which is where it is beneficial to have indexes other than the shard key.

Comment: So, we can use create unique index for shard key and mongodb will guarantee uniqueness across shards? But we can't guarantee uniqueness of unique key that is not shard key (or shard key is the prefix of unique index), right?

Comment: Yes, you can create unique indexes for shard keys and MongoDb will guarantee uniqueness across shards.  You cannot guarantee the uniqueness of a unique key that is not the shard key and you cannot guarantee the uniqueness of a key that is only part of a unique shard key.  MongoDb can guarantee only the complete key is unique (not part of it) in the case of unique compound shard keys.

Comment: `[E]ach shard cannot report on whether it contains the key to be inserted is unique' because insert and indexing operations are local to each shard, per [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/).